# Where is the code which populates DataObjects' protected $_data property?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, installation, debugging, debug

For the second time in as many months, I'm debugging an issue where a key expected to be found in the `Magento\Framework\DataObject` class' `$_data` array is expected but not found. Last time, I tried to identify all the places that write to that array, alas, the constructor, `setData()` method, and related methods in that class were not enough. Maybe an extending class extends one of those methods or writes directly, I don't know.

My particular issue this time is that the `store_id` key is missing, on a fresh 2.4.3 install into an empty database. Therefore page loads to the index page return "The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.". I'll probably just reinstall and pray, but I see that I need to learn to debug this commonly-used critical array.

**Where is the code which populates DataObjects' protected $_data property with the 'store_id' key?**

```
$ grep -r store_id * | grep -i setData | wc -l
48
```

Shall I put breakpoints on all 48 locations and try to find it? I stress that this is a brand new 2.4.3 install on a clean database with no modules. Just `composer create-project` and `bin/magento setup:install`.

Comment: I would start from the class where the error is coming from and follow the parent classes.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri: The code that populates the `$_data` property is not a frame in the stack trace. Apparently some bootstrapping happens, during which these properties are populated, and only afterwards are the controllers invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: `\Magento\Framework\DataObject::__call` and also at `\Magento\Framework\DataObject::_underscore` to see how this methods are working under the hood.

In short, when objects from classes that extend `Magento\Framework\DataObject` call methods prefixed with: `get`, `set`, `uns` and `has` this is internally handled by `DataObject::__call` method to do proper action.
This means that it's not needed to explicitly call `$object->setData('property_name', 'value')` but is also possible to do it with `$object->setPropertyName()`

Obviously this does not apply if in extended classes these methods are overwritten.

But in your case, maybe the best way to find what's going on is to check in `pub/index.php` which store code is being passed when calling bootstrap since it looks like magento is complaining about non existent store code.

Comment: Thank you, I'll put breakpoints on these methods as well next time.